# how to load media from another app django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-media

I have two apps *accounts* and *home* in *tutorial* project.
A user can create a post in *home app* and I'm able to render post(i.e images and post data) in home app. In *accounts app* I want to create a search page where not logged in user can search and view the posts.

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tutorial/media/')
```

*search.html*

```
{% load static %}
 {% if re %}
    {% for q in re %}
    <a href="{% url 'home:Post_detail' pk=q.id %}">{{q.id}}.{{ q.post }}
        <br>
        <img src="{{ q.image.url}}"  width="240" height="auto">
        <p>Posted by {{ q.user.get_full_name }} on {{ q.created }}</p>

    {%endfor%}
    {% endif %}
```

I use the above code in both *home app* and *accounts app*. It works fine for *home* app but not for *accounts app*
when I see view source page I get perfect url in accounts app **(search.html)** but, the images are not loading properly [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsiuy.png)

**project urls.py**

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls' , namespace='accounts') ),
    path('home/', include('home.urls' , namespace='home') ),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',login_redirect , name = 'login_redirect'),
    ]
    if settings.DEBUG is True:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**tutorial project structure**

```
tutorial
    |_accounts
    |_home
    |_tutorial
       |_media
          |_profile_images
             |_all image files
```

Comment: What url it forms for images?

Comment: it takes me to the media folder in tutorial project /media/profile_image/Screenshot_5.png